# Using BDP Formula (Bloomberg) via VBA without pasting the formula in an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I was wondering if it is possible to use the bdp-formula from Bloomberg in VBA without pasting it into an excel cell. I know that you can use the bdp-formula in VBA in the following way:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=BDP(""XYZ"",""PX_LAST"")/100"
```

However I want to do the calculations completely in VBA without the necessity to use the corresponding Excel formula by pasting the formula to a specific cell.

Comment: That's not possible but you can use the COM API from VBA, which enables you to query Bloomberg programmatic. The syntax is a bit different and you need to parse the responses. If you google around you may be able to find examples or even libraries that do most of the work for you.